# Android Q : Read audio file from folder path

Tags: mediastore, android-10.0

I have an audio file in the folder path
**/storage/emulated/legcy/Download/play.mp3**
Previously from
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
I used to read the song but it doesn't work right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using [getExternalStoragePyblicDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) in Android Q, as such method **has been deprecated**.

In Android Q new restrictions are applied when accessing media.
The recommended way is to use the [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) API or [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider).

See the next link for more details about scoped storage in Android Q, and how to access files:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped